# Check if array of objects contains a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of `UILocalNotification`s. In each notification there is a `userInfo` property which is a `NSDictionary`. In the userInfo I set a key `@"ID"` and the value is a unique ID.

So what I want to do is check if the array of notifications if any userInfo property has a value `@"test"` for key `@"ID"` then return `YES` otherwise `NO`. I know how to achieve this with a for loop but I'm wondering if there might be a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-[NSArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:]` which takes a block that return YES for matching objects, NO otherwise:

```
NSArray *array = ...;
NSIndexSet *matchingIndexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(UILocalNotification *notification, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [notification.userInfo[@"ID"] isEqualToString:@"test"];
}];
return [matchingIndexes count] != 0;
```

Comment: Performance-wise is this preferred over a for loop? If not I would vote for the for loop because it's (for me) more readable.

Comment: I would avoid [premature optimazation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil), this works, and it does what you want, do you really think that you are generating enough notifications for this to become a performance issue?

Comment: When is it necessary to set the `BOOL *stop = YES` ?

Comment: You can set `*stop = YES` if you want to stop enumerating (which is what this is doing internally of course) early. In other words `*stop = YES` is the equivalent of `break` in a for loop. In this case, you could stop early as soon as you found the first object with a ID of test, to avoid unnecessarily continuing to check for matching objects even though you know the answer is YES.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that you're unlikely to do much better performance-wise than basic fast enumeration -- maybe using one of the "enumerate with options" methods, allowing concurrency -- but there are certainly more elegant ways to write what you're trying to do:

```
[[array valueForKeyPath:@"userInfo.ID"] containsObject:@"test"];
```